# Add target to all subfolders

Tags: cmake

I'm working on a library project built as follows

```
Base/
  CMakeLists.txt
  src/
  tools/
     CMakeLists.txt
  tests/
     CMakeLists.txt
  debug/
  release/
```

The main `CMakeLists.txt`, in `Base/` contains the target to build the library whose source is in `src/` and I have a configure to create  `debug/` and `release/` and call `cmake -DCMAKE_RELEASE_TYPE=<DEBUG|RELEASE> ..` to get the build structures.

This results in the following structure

```
debug/
   Makefile
   tests/
      Makefile
   tools/
      Makefile
```

The programs built in `tools/` and `tests/` create output files and I'm trying to create a `clean_output` target to every Makefile in the created build structure.

I've used `add_custom_target(clean_output rm -rf *.ext)` But it doesn't carry to the Makefile files in `tests/` and `tools/`.  I've tried to add the same command in the `CMakeLists.txt` files in those directories, but I get an error message that I can't define a target already defined within the same project.

I have tried to use `WORKING_DRECTORY` in combination with `CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR` and `CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR` to no avail.

Does anyone know how to define a custom target in all the directories of a project?

**EDIT:** I am not trying to add files to the standard `clean` target.  I'm trying to create an additional `clean_output` target to remove some files while keeping the executables in place.

Comment: Cmake has built in clean target. Try using `set_directory_properties(directory ADDITIONAL_MAKE_CLEAN_FILES files)`

Comment: But that would still delete the executables right?  I'm trying to setup a target to clean out the outputs files only.  Before porting my project to cmake, I had three different targets, `clean`, `clean_all` and `clean_output`.

Answer (score 2):

You can specify working directory and several commands to execute in one target.
BTW you can use `cmake -E remove_directory`:

```
add_custom_target(
    clean_output
    COMMAND
    "${CMAKE_COMMAND}" -E remove_directory "${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/directory/with/exts"
    COMMAND
    "${CMAKE_COMMAND}" -E remove_directory "${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/other-dir/with/exts"
    WORKING_DIRECTORY
    "${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}"
)
```

Comment: I rewrote it using `CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR` and it works for the root build directory, but it still doesn't add targets to the Makefiles in sub-directories (I've edited details on what it looks like).  Is there no way to add a target to all the Makefiles?

Comment: @Lexiel I doubt this is possible because cmake designed to be a cross-platform tool. And what you asking is only applied to Makefile, but it doesn't make sense for such generator like `Xcode`. BTW AFAIK make has `-C` option, so have you tried `make -C .. targetname`?

Comment: Thanks.  `make -C .. clean_output` is what I do right now, I was hoping to be able to have local targets in the structure.  Especially since the directory structure will become more complex as the project develops.  But if it's impossible within cmake, I'll look for a workaround instead.

Comment: @Lexiel `I'll look for a workaround instead` IMHO you need to look at this issue from different angle. May be it's better organize this run in test (`add_test`) or add option `--clear-output` to your testing application (?)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your questions, you can accomplish what you want with [**set_directory_properties ADDITIONAL_MAKE_CLEAN_FILES**](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.8/cmake.html#command%3aset_directory_properties)

Comment: That's good to know, but it's not exactly what I'm trying to do.  I edited my question to make it clearer.